# Why does object.observe not work for the value property of an input field?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object.observe

I was playing with Object.observe in the latest version of Chrome and was wondering why it does not work for the 'value' property of a text input. The code below will log a change for adding/changing the 'foo' property, but not for changing the value property. Anybody know why?

```
var myTextInput = document.getElementById('myTextInput');

Object.observe(myTextInput, function(changes){

  changes.forEach(function(change) {
    console.log(change);
  });

});

myTextInput.value = 'test123';
myTextInput.foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: Maybe because DOM nodes are host objects and can basically do whatever they want (kind of). Also note that `Object.observe` is part of ES7, highly experimental and not finalized.

Comment: The `.value` DOM property is implemented as a getter/setter afair, so it doesn't really change.

Comment: @Bergi That seems like what it could be. MutationObservers also don't pick up the value property of inputs for probably the same reason. I wonder how value is stored then.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why this is, but since you're observing a DOM element's attributes, the [mutation observer api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) may be more appropriate.

Comment: That doesn't work on the value property either. Tried it and got nothing. Addy Osmani pointed this out as well in this article (at the bottom under "limitations"): http://addyosmani.com/blog/mutation-observers/